# NullPointerException when binding ConfigurationProperties (Spring Boot)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, nullpointerexception

I am struggling with some code and I don't have a clue why...
Here is my code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(WorkflowRootProperties.class)
@ComponentScan
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class TestApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

And my properties bean

```
@ConfigurationProperties("workflow")
public class WorkflowRootProperties {
    private List<Datacenter> datacenter = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Datacenter> getDatacenter() {
        return datacenter;
    }

    public void setDatacenter(List<Datacenter> datacenter) {
        this.datacenter = datacenter;
    }
}
```

Which references another bean

```
public class EnvProperties {
    public static class Datacenter {
        private List<Env> env = new ArrayList<>();

        public List<Env> getEnv() {
            return env;
        }

        public void setEnv(List<Env> env) {
            this.env = env;
        }
    }

    public static class Env {
        private List<Instance> instance = new ArrayList<>();

        public List<Instance> getInstance() {
            return instance;
        }

        public void setInstance(List<Instance> instance) {
            this.instance = instance;
        }
    }

    public static class Instance {
        private String port;

        public String getPort() {
            return port;
        }

        public void setPort(String port) {
            this.port= port;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, my properties are

```
workflow.datacenter[1].env[1].instance[1].port=8080
workflow.datacenter[2].env[1].instance[1].port=8082
workflow.datacenter[1].env[1].instance[2].port=8080
```

My Error is at init, I get a NPE which I cannot understand.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext...
>
> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed
>   to bind properties under 'workflow.datacenter' to
>   java.util.List     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.handleBindError(Binder.java:250)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:226)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.lambda$bindBean$4(Binder.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder.bind(JavaBeanBinder.java:72)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder.bind(JavaBeanBinder.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder.bind(JavaBeanBinder.java:53)...
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null     at
>   java.util.TreeMap.compare(TreeMap.java:1294)  at
>   java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:538)   at
>   java.util.TreeSet.add(TreeSet.java:255)   at
>   java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:169)
>     at
>   java.util.LinkedList$LLSpliterator.forEachRemaining(LinkedList.java:1235)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:270)
>     at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)   at
>   java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.IndexedElementsBinder.assertNoUnboundChildren(IndexedElementsBinder.java:137)...

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 3):

Seems to work if you start indexing from 0:

```
workflow.datacenter[0].env[0].instance[0].port=8080
workflow.datacenter[1].env[0].instance[0].port=8082
workflow.datacenter[0].env[0].instance[1].port=8080
```

Comment: Whaou Thanks a lot! You made my day! It was working before upgrading spring boot version to 2.0.0 (+other stuff) which is why i did not think of this!

Comment: You're welcome and yeah, they changed properties binding: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Relaxed-Binding-2.0
See 'Constrants'